# NG-REPEAT Shows nothing..Even data parsed successfully

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

**Html Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="searching">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular_JS</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Angular_JS/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ctrl.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div>
      <table>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>TITLE</th>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat='entry in data'>
          <td>{{entry.id}}</td>
          <td>{{entry.title}}</td>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**ctrl.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('searching', []);

myApp.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http) {
  console.log('Initiating Controller');
  $http.get('content.php').then(function successCallback(data) {
    $scope.entries = data;
    console.log(data);
  },function errorCallback(){
    alert("Error Occured");
  });
}]);
```

**content.php**

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('ias');

  $q = "SELECT * FROM tbl_question_category";
  $res = mysql_query($q);

  while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $data[] = array('id'=>$rows['question_category_id'],'title'=>$rows['category_title']);
  }
  $jso1 = json_encode($data);
  print_r ($jso1);
?>
```

[This will be the Result...Click to see the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEepn.png)

But it shows nothing on the Browser screen...
[This is the Browser output....Click to see the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y26Di.png)

I'm looking for good answers...Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

The `$http.get()` method returns a response object, not the data directly. So the `ng-repeat` directive is actually trying to iterate over this response object, and not your data.

The other thing is that you're using the wrong scope variable. You're assigning the data to `$scope.entries`, but trying to iterate over `$scope.data` in the ng-repeat.

So to make it do what you want, you simply change your controller and view to the following:

```
myApp.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http) {
  console.log('Initiating Controller');
  $http.get('content.php').then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.entries = response.data;
    console.log(response.data);
  },function errorCallback(){
    alert("Error Occured");
  });
}]);


<tr ng-repeat='entry in entries'>
    <td>{{entry.id}}</td>
    <td>{{entry.title}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Bro so many thankz to you....I changed 'data' to 'response'...Atlast it worked perfectly.....Thats the Problem..You're just rocking!!!Thankxxx

Comment: No problem mate. If this solves your problem, please consider marking this answer as accepted.

Comment: Oh sorry..I'm new to Stackoverflow...So how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You are using incorrect scope property in view

Change:

```
<tr ng-repeat='entry in data'>
```

To

```
<tr ng-repeat='entry in entries'>
```

so that it corresponds with `$scope.entries` assigned in controller

Answer (score 0):

You're binding the results to $scope.entries and in ng-repeat you're trying to iterate over $scope.data.

Either change in your controller callback $scope.entries to $scope.data or on your view change ng-repeat='entry in data' to ng-repeat='entry in entries'

Comment: Ohh sry,I changed but still its not show anything??

Answer (score 0):

var myApp = angular.module('searching', []);

```
myApp.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http) {
  console.log('Initiating Controller');
  $http.get('content.php').then(function successCallback(data) {
    $scope.entries = data.data;
    console.log(data);
  },function errorCallback(){
    alert("Error Occured");
  });
}]);
 <tr ng-repeat='entry in entries'>
          <td>{{entry.id}}</td>
          <td>{{entry.title}}</td>
          </tr>
```

Please use above code .you are using data while you have to use data.data